# sprintf works fine, sprintf_s gives Access Violation Error

Tags: printf

I have been using the md5 implementation found in this page:

http://www.zedwood.com/article/121/cpp-md5-function

As it is it works fine. There is however this function:

```
// return hex representation of digest as string
std::string MD5::hexdigest() const
{
  if (!finalized)
    return "";

  char buf[33];
  for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
    sprintf(buf+i*2, "%02x", digest[i]);
  buf[32]=0;

  return std::string(buf);
}
```

If I change sprintf to the safe version (sprintf_s), then I get an Access Violation Error at runtime. The only thing I change is the sprintf line, like this:

```
    sprintf_s(buf+i*2, 33, "%02x", digest[i]);
```

It compiles fine but then I get the error. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you pass an offset into your buffer, you also need to reduce the size you pass to `snprintf_s`. That is:

```
snprintf_s(buf+i*2, 33-2*i, "%02x", digest[i]);
```